# Making a sliding door that is unlocked with a key in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make a sliding door for my unity level and I've managed to set up the animations but the scripting that's supposed to link up the functions with the objects isn't working.

Here's the script for the key card:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Key_Pickup_1 : MonoBehaviour {


public GameObject player;
private Player_inventory playerinventory;

void Awake ()
{
    playerinventory = player.GetComponent<Player_inventory>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void onTriggerEnter()
   {

    if (gameObject == player)
    {
        playerinventory.hasKey_1 = true;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

   }
}
```

Here's the script for the Door animation:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class Door_Animation_1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public string Open;
    private Animator anim_1;
    public GameObject player;
    private Player_inventory playerInventory;

    void Start()
{
    anim_1 = GetComponent<Animator>();
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    playerInventory = player.GetComponent<Player_inventory>();
}

void OntriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject == player)
    {
        if (playerInventory.hasKey_1)
        {
            anim_1.SetTrigger(Open);

        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: c# is not a script language

Comment: this is not the place to ask "why isn't my code working". Update your question and tell us the approach you followed to debug the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @FirstStep I don't think he is calling it a scripting language.  Code attached to components are referred to as scripts in Unity.  "Unity allows you to create your own Components using scripts. These allow you to trigger game events, modify Component properties over time and respond to user input in any way you like." From their Manual.

Comment: @Timmy oh cool thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the proper capitalization for the [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) methods in your code.  You have two different spellings and they are both wrong.  It must be *exactly* `OnTriggerEnter` (or `OnTriggerEnter2D` for objects with a `Collider2D` instead of a `Collider`).